# A more formal word for the verb "bagging"

Tags: verbs, synonyms

I'm creating process documentation for a company and there is a phase I called "bagging", in which, literally, you put stuff inside bags.

This is in the context of finance operations.  We're bagging money and cheques to be sent via secure courier to be deposited.

However, I find using the verb "bagging" to sound... really crude.  Is there a better term for this?

Comment: I would have thought a term that was a clear description of what it represented would be the best.

Comment: Try the word “parceling”.  I’ve heard it used in supermarkets for packing groceries.

Comment: *Pack* is fine.  Maybe also *batch* or *bundle*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid sounding too informal, the OP could use "bagged" in a passive construction e.g.

> Cash and cheques are **bagged** and sent off via…"

If the perfectly acceptable verb *bag* still bothers the OP, possible alternatives could be "packed", "packaged", or "closed/sealed in bags"

> Cash, cheques and other valuables are **packed** and sent off via…

Comment: I used the term "Pack" and it looks better.